# My STM32F407VET6 is no connecting to STM32CubeIDE. what could be the problem?

Tags: stm32, st-link

I would like to say that i was taking Udemy Course related to Embedded C - Absolute Beginners. So everything was firsthand base on tutorial's installation. It was explain how to install IDE but hardware setup wasn't detailed compare to coding/software one. this are the chronological order:

1. i first i try to install the STM32CubeIDE. in the pre-installation there is an option to install **Segger J-Link Drivers and ST-Link Drivers**. **i both check** so i should have both install....
2. next, since do not have hardware by that time, i just do coding. my project are building properly when i compile it so im expecting its not coding problem. so i assume this latter problem is either hardware, firmware or PC port problem.
3. finally, the STM32F407VET6 was delivered and has a mini USB included. so i tried to connect it to my device and run simple LED Blink but when i try to Run As/Debug As to 1STM32C/C++Application, it doesnt compile. it says *"No ST-Link Detected! Please connect ST-LINK and Restart the debug session".*
4. So in the Udemy's Q&A i tried to keep searching and some people said i should install this 2: [STSW-Link007](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stsw-link007.html) and [STSW-Link009](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stsw-link009.html)
5. ok i downloaded both, extracted and tried them. first, **i removed my usb cable then install Link009's file**. just typical installation and everything seems ok

[image]

6. now i tried to **open the STSW-Link007** and reconnect my usb cable to my laptop. when i opened the STSW-Link007, this is where another problem kicks in: as you can see below it there is another error --- *"No ST-Link Device Detected! Please connect ST-LINK and Restart the debug session".*

[image]

7. I even try to change port and usb cable since i have other usb cable but nothing works.

So im very confused. i have no progress at all. first there is no ST-Link detected in STM32CubeIDE and now to STSW-Link007. **So i would like to ask. What could be the problem** I've been doing this for 1 and a half day. This is my first time interfacing with STM32 pheripheral so there might be something i missed....

Others:
in a 1 Q&A of that Udemy Course, someone said i should do this: in the [Getting Started in Page 9 of this Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00039084-discovery-kit-with-stm32f407vg-mcu-stmicroelectronics.pdf) i should follow the steps. but i cant exactly follow it as there is different ports in my STM32. so i do not know the equivalent of that in my VET6. additionally im not sure if this is the correct solution as well, though worth mentioning if one of the solution, if not the exact solution.

My STM32F407
[image]
My STM32F407 when ported to laptop. the D1 Led is on but not blinking or something. just light up/HIGH.
[image]

i highly appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: Weird to use a 5 pin header strip for SWD connector, I haven't seen that before. They could have used a right angle 2x5 1.27mm standard connector but cheaped out, I guess?

Answer (score 2):

There is no probem. You simply don't have a programmer/debugger, such as ST-Link or J-link, so CubeIDE can't connect to one.

So the error messages are true and to program or debug the board using ST-Link or J-link, you actually need such an adapter.

Since your board is not an ST Discovery Board, the manual of ST Discovery Board does not apply to whatever board you might have. The ST Discovery Boards do have a built-in ST-Link adapter, your board doesn't.

So basically, you don't have a STM32F407VET6 as a bare MCU, you don't have an ST Discovery Board with STM32F407VET6 and ST-Link, you have some random board from some other manufacturer which is completely different. Your board has a STM32F407VET6 and a completely different set of hardware even if it has a STM32F407VET6. But it contains no ST-Link.

Comment: thank you for answering. i would like to ask. when you said thati need such an adapter, are you refering to similar to this or this exactly? https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/st-link-v2.html

Comment: It's up to you which ST-Link you want to use, but only ST makes genuine ST-Links. If made by someone else, they are just clones. Also for the price of a separate ST-Link, you might be able to buy a Discovery Board which already includes an ST-Link.

Comment: @DreacLeoson If you indent to marry ST and live together forever after (even when ST constantly cheats on you and delivers all manufactured parts to someone else) then go ahead and get an ST Link. Otherwise get a J-Link and similar which doesn't assume ST but works with any Cortex M no matter brand.